# Simperium Updates "Freezing" device until finished

Tags: simperium

Hi Simperium Developers.

I am building an iOS app using your data platform, as I go deeper into final testing I see this issue as the amount of coredata increases the app "freezes" as it is update.

The issue is very apparent when a user who has been using my iPad version of the app moves to another device and they are syncing the large dataset for the first time to a new device, but I see similar behaviour for small changes too.

So I see the following in the Log

Simperium enqueuing 253 object requests (PeopleModel)

Simperium enqueuing 301 object requests (SeatsModel)

Simperium enqueuing 139 object requests (KeywordModel)

etc.

I have approx 20 Entities in total

Then the app appears to hang the user interface until I see

Simperium finished processing index for PeopleModel

Simperium finished processing index for SeatsModel

Simperium finished processing index for KeywordModel

There can be many minutes of wait between the enqueuing and finsheed processing messages.

If I turn on verbose logging I only see additional information as each object is enqueued - no errors or warnings...

Is there anything I can do/change in my iOS app to release the rest of the app to continue processing ...?

HELP !

Cheers

Steve

Hi Mike,

Thanks for the quick reply, adding useWebsockets appears to make things slightly better. On the smaller updates it definitely helped. But when I do a main sync (i.e. the scenario where a user is syncing a dataset that exists in the cloud already , for example when they link a new device and the data already exists) I see the same "freezing" behavior , I then received this CRASH :

Simperium websocket failed with error Error Domain=org.lolrus.SocketRocket Code=2145 "Error writing to stream" UserInfo=0x28b85f60 {NSLocalizedDescription=Error writing to stream}
2013-05-13 19:29:56.898 MeetingPad[652:907] *** -[SRWebSocket send:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1d172bc0

I tried the test 3 more times but I didn't see the websocket error above again... so possibly not relevant.

My coredata is about 2.4MB in size - here is the full console output, any more thoughts would be appreciated.... I would be happy to popup a message to the user simply saying "Syncing Please Wait" but I'm unsure how to know when the sync has finished to remove the message.....

```
2013-05-13 20:09:37.367 MeetingPad[897:907] Init DropBox
2013-05-13 20:09:37.575 MeetingPad[897:907] Init MPIAPHelper
2013-05-13 20:09:37.588 MeetingPad[897:1803] NETWORK REACHABLE!
2013-05-13 20:09:37.676 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium error: bucket list not loaded. Ensure Simperium is started before any objects are fetched.
2013-05-13 20:09:37.702 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium error: bucket list not loaded. Ensure Simperium is started before any objects are fetched.
2013-05-13 20:09:37:928 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium didn't find an existing auth token
2013-05-13 20:09:37:956 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium starting... 
2013-05-13 20:09:37:960 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium loaded 21 entity definitions
2013-05-13 20:09:37.977 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium managing 0 ActionLinks82 object instances
2013-05-13 20:09:38.000 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium managing 1 Relationship1Model82 object instances
2013-05-13 20:09:38.004 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium managing 0 AttendeeModel82 object instances
2013-05-13 20:09:38.010 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium managing 0 ClipModel82 object instances
2013-05-13 20:09:38.015 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium managing 0 ShapesModel82 object instances
2013-05-13 20:09:38.020 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium managing 0 SeatModel82 object instances
2013-05-13 20:09:38.026 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium managing 0 AgendaItemModel82 object instances
2013-05-13 20:09:38.031 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium managing 0 PointsModel82 object instances
2013-05-13 20:09:38.036 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium managing 0 AgendaItemVersionModel82 object instances
2013-05-13 20:09:38.040 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium managing 0 Relationship2Model82 object instances
2013-05-13 20:09:38.044 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium managing 0 ImagesModel82 object instances
2013-05-13 20:09:38.054 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium managing 1 SeatingPlanModel82 object instances
2013-05-13 20:09:38.075 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium managing 0 NoteLink82 object instances
2013-05-13 20:09:38.080 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium managing 0 RecordingModel82 object instances
2013-05-13 20:09:38.085 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium managing 0 ActionsModel82 object instances
2013-05-13 20:09:38.089 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium managing 0 KeywordLinks82 object instances
2013-05-13 20:09:38.093 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium managing 0 PeopleLinks82 object instances
2013-05-13 20:09:38.098 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium managing 0 EvernoteDeletions82 object instances
2013-05-13 20:09:38.105 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium managing 6 StylesModel82 object instances
2013-05-13 20:09:38.107 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium managing 1 NotesModel82 object instances
2013-05-13 20:09:38.111 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium managing 0 PeopleModel82 object instances
2013-05-13 20:09:38:116 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium didn't find an existing auth token
2013-05-13 20:09:54:931 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium authenticating: https://auth.simperium.com/1/wqqewweqeqw-disabeqweqwilities-33we2/authorize/
2013-05-13 20:09:56:010 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium authentication success!
2013-05-13 20:09:56.150 MeetingPad[897:907] Reachability Flag Status: -R ------- networkStatusForFlags
2013-05-13 20:09:56:151 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium starting network managers...
2013-05-13 20:09:56.151 MeetingPad[897:907] Opening Connection...
2013-05-13 20:09:57:855 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 106 objects from index (ClipModel82)
2013-05-13 20:09:57:878 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium enqueuing 106 object requests (ClipModel82)
2013-05-13 20:09:58:069 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 290 objects from index (AttendeeModel82)
2013-05-13 20:09:58:124 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium enqueuing 290 object requests (AttendeeModel82)
2013-05-13 20:09:58:173 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 223 objects from index (ShapesModel82)
2013-05-13 20:09:58:175 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 28 objects from index (ImagesModel82)
2013-05-13 20:09:58:176 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 47 objects from index (Relationship2Model82)
2013-05-13 20:09:58:196 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium enqueuing 47 object requests (Relationship2Model82)
2013-05-13 20:09:58:205 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium enqueuing 28 object requests (ImagesModel82)
2013-05-13 20:09:58:232 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 100 objects from index (Relationship1Model82)
2013-05-13 20:09:58:234 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium enqueuing 223 object requests (ShapesModel82)
2013-05-13 20:09:58:256 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium enqueuing 100 object requests (Relationship1Model82)
2013-05-13 20:09:58:276 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 250 objects from index (ActionLinks82)
2013-05-13 20:09:58:322 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 251 objects from index (SeatingPlanModel82)
2013-05-13 20:09:58:348 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium enqueuing 250 object requests (ActionLinks82)
2013-05-13 20:09:58:378 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium enqueuing 251 object requests (SeatingPlanModel82)
2013-05-13 20:09:58:383 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 155 objects from index (RecordingModel82)
2013-05-13 20:09:58:412 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium enqueuing 155 object requests (RecordingModel82)
2013-05-13 20:09:58:442 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 24 objects from index (StylesModel82)
2013-05-13 20:09:58:449 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium enqueuing 24 object requests (StylesModel82)
2013-05-13 20:09:58:471 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 232 objects from index (NoteLink82)
2013-05-13 20:09:58:482 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 289 objects from index (ActionsModel82)
2013-05-13 20:09:58:486 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 248 objects from index (NotesModel82)
2013-05-13 20:09:58:500 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 295 objects from index (PeopleLinks82)
2013-05-13 20:09:58:593 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium enqueuing 232 object requests (NoteLink82)
2013-05-13 20:09:58:655 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium enqueuing 248 object requests (NotesModel82)
2013-05-13 20:09:58:686 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium enqueuing 295 object requests (PeopleLinks82)
2013-05-13 20:09:58:696 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium enqueuing 289 object requests (ActionsModel82)
2013-05-13 20:09:59:987 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 481 objects from index (PointsModel82)
2013-05-13 20:10:00:073 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 275 objects from index (SeatModel82)
2013-05-13 20:10:00:080 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 267 objects from index (KeywordLinks82)
2013-05-13 20:10:00:088 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 220 objects from index (PeopleModel82)
2013-05-13 20:10:00:092 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium enqueuing 481 object requests (PointsModel82)
2013-05-13 20:10:00:450 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium enqueuing 220 object requests (PeopleModel82)
2013-05-13 20:10:00:461 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium enqueuing 267 object requests (KeywordLinks82)
2013-05-13 20:10:00:461 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium enqueuing 275 object requests (SeatModel82)
2013-05-13 20:13:29.671 MeetingPad[897:907] Opening Connection...
2013-05-13 20:13:30:598 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 100 objects from index (Relationship1Model82)
2013-05-13 20:13:30:706 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 250 objects from index (ActionLinks82)
2013-05-13 20:13:30:743 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 290 objects from index (AttendeeModel82)
2013-05-13 20:13:30:804 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 106 objects from index (ClipModel82)
2013-05-13 20:13:30:806 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 47 objects from index (Relationship2Model82)
2013-05-13 20:13:30:846 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 275 objects from index (SeatModel82)
2013-05-13 20:13:30:858 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 28 objects from index (ImagesModel82)
2013-05-13 20:13:30:870 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 155 objects from index (RecordingModel82)
2013-05-13 20:13:30:948 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 223 objects from index (ShapesModel82)
2013-05-13 20:13:30:955 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 267 objects from index (KeywordLinks82)
2013-05-13 20:13:30:977 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 481 objects from index (PointsModel82)
2013-05-13 20:13:31:011 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 232 objects from index (NoteLink82)
2013-05-13 20:13:31:053 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 289 objects from index (ActionsModel82)
2013-05-13 20:13:31:062 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 295 objects from index (PeopleLinks82)
2013-05-13 20:13:31:076 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 24 objects from index (StylesModel82)
2013-05-13 20:13:31:338 MeetingPad[897:907] Simperium processing 220 objects from index (PeopleModel82)
2013-05-13 20:14:34.901 MeetingPad[897:907] Opening Connection...
```

Comment: Does anything change if you set useWebSockets to YES on your Simperium instance?

Comment: Hi Mike I added a response in the main question above ...

Comment: Looks like a lot of data across a lot of buckets. Nice. To check for completion, you experiments with `setAllBucketDelegates:` and the `SPBucketDelegate` protocol. The method you're looking for is `bucketDidFinishIndexing:` where you should be able to count the number of buckets that have finished downloading all the initial data.

Comment: Thanks  again Mike , the issue still exists in that the main thread is blocked while Simperium Enqueues etc - there are moments when the the thread is released long enough for me to update a "Syncing" message to the screen but this is sporadic and gives the user a less than ideal experience as the interface is non responsive for around 1 minute. Is there anything else that might help ...?

Comment: All of Simperium's processing is designed to be off the main thread, but it sounds like you're hitting a limit of some kind. Are you able to debug and perhaps use Xcode's profiler to pinpoint what's causing the blocking?

Comment: Hi Mike, I have emailed to contact@simperium.com the output from the profiler that may help ....

Comment: Hi Mike I built a new, clean, simple coredata/simperium iOS project today using the same datamodel as Im using for my App. I used the Xcode template for a coredata project and the instructions you provide for adding Simperium, so all is basic and clean.The app only starts simperium and provides a basic tableview of the contents of the data. I get the same "freezing behaviour" for the large dataset. I have emailed the project and login details to the test data set to you at contact@simperium.com can you take a look? Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the comment below? I suggest you check for both use of `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` and any Simperium callbacks that are called when data changes to make sure you're not updating your view too aggressively for that initial pull.

Comment: Hi Mike, yes I reviewed the comment below, I removed ALL callbacks from Simperium (I was using Bucket Delegate only) and checked for NSManagedObjectContectDidChange which I was not using, same issue. Did you see my comment above about sending you an iOS project which connects to the datamodel and data you can investigate the issue in a few minutes with this? Please review this it may be easier than the comments back and forward on here .. is contact@simperium.com the best way to share this with you, did you receive it?

Comment: This issue can be tracked here: https://github.com/Simperium/simperium-ios/issues/62

Answer (score 1):

The sheer amount of data you were syncing across a large number of buckets exposed some performance problems. These have been fixed with [this commit](https://github.com/Simperium/simperium-ios/commit/4f173f6ca1b7f542888c2994bf72b9bd3d593e61).

In particular:

1. `NSNotifications` for added/changed objects were being triggered very aggressively while indexing. Since most people don't seem to make use of these anyway (during indexing), they've been removed for now. They're still fired when objects are added/changed otherwise.
2. The storage of metadata that tracks pending relationships has been moved from `NSUserDefaults` to metadata directly on the `NSPersistentStore`.
3. The resolution of pending relationships has been moved to its own GCD queue, since it touches the database potentially very frequently during indexing.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the quick turn around with this issue. I have been testing this over the last few weeks - things are MUCH better, I still get a minimal issue when tested against iPad 2 which causes almost no impact, the iPhone is perfect too. The iPhone 4 still shows significant "blocking" of the main UI. I assume due to it's significantly reduced processing power. So thanks for the support with this, things overall are much improved.